# React Changing style of two buttons on click

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to change background-color with more than one buttons onClick function?

this code will change both buttons(init is black color) color at the same time.

I wanna be that the button that I click changes color but another one doesn't change.

ex.First time, Btn1 black, btn2 black

Then I click btn1, btn1 white btn2 black,

Then I click btn2, btn1 white, btn2 white.

Then I click btn2, btn1 white, btn2 black.

```
class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
    super();


    this.state = {
        color_black: true
      }
    }

    changeColor(){
            this.setState({color_black: !this.state.color_black})
    }
        render(){
        let bgColor = this.state.color_black ? "black" : "white"
        return (
        <div>
            <button style={{backgroundColor: bgColor}} onClick={this.changeColor.bind(this)}>Button1</button>

            <button style={{backgroundColor: bgColor}} onClick={this.changeColor.bind(this)}>Button2</button>
        </div>
      )
    }
}

React.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simple solution will be putting your buttons in seperate components, than rendering them inside parent component. Since a component can only have one state at the time, seperation is neccessary. Lots of code? Yes. Does It work? Also yes.

```
/*
 * A simple React component
 */
class Button extends React.Component {   
    constructor(){
    super(); 
    this.state = {
        color_black: true,
      }
    }
    changeColor(){
            this.setState({color_black: !this.state.color_black})
    }
        render(){
        let bgColor = this.state.color_black ? this.props.color : this.props.color2
        return (
        <div>
            <button style={{backgroundColor: bgColor}} onClick={this.changeColor.bind(this)}>Button1</button>
        </div>
      )
    }
}

class Application extends React.Component {
        render(){
        return (
        <div>
            <Button color="blue" color2="red"/>
            <Button color="black" color2="white"/>
        </div>    
      )
    }
}
/*
 * Render the above component into the div#app
 */
React.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Is there any solution by using in one file? since there are two or more buttons

Comment: Ahhh, Juan is right, you can just use ONE class button than put multiple buttons inside Application class. I'm adding props to let bgColor so you change your button's colors easily from Application class.

Comment: As for your question, sure why not, just seperate the button and application classes, thou react heavely encourages seperate files and import

Answer (score 1):

The best solution will be putting your buttons in separate class. Since each one of them will manage its own state. This way you will be able to handle as many buttons as you link and each one of them will change it's color when is pressed.

```
/*
 * A simple React component
 */
class Button extends React.Component {   
    constructor(props){
        super(props); 
        this.state = {
            color_black: true
        }
        this.changeColor = this.changeColor.bind(this);
    }

    changeColor(){
        this.setState({color_black: !this.state.color_black})
    }

    render(){
        let bgColor = this.state.color_black ? "black" : "white"
        return (
            <div>
                <button style={{backgroundColor: bgColor}} onClick={this.changeColor}>Button1</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


class Application extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <Button/>
                <Button/>
            </div>    
        );
    }
}
/*
 * Render the above component into the div#app
 */
React.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```